# URL Canonicalization for WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, canonicalization

I have the website `drwagenberg.com` which can open on both URLs:

```
http://www.drwagenberg.com/
http://drwagenberg.com/
```

I want to canonicalize the URL `http://drwagenberg.com/`, so that whenever the user types this URL it automatically makes it http://www.drwagenberg.com/

Keep in mind that the website is built in WordPress.

I've tried different methods like redirection in my `.htacess` file. Here is the code I used:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.drwagenberg.com/
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^drwagenberg\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.drwagenberg.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Try this. And get rid of the top line

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.drwagenberg.com/
```

Comment: Hey Nothing Happend the same problem i.e no www. appended to the url.